# How to output the content of a variable in ZF2?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have started to learn Zend Framework 2 and I've got a problem with how to output the content of a variable from a class.

```
I wrote a simple class like below:

 <?php
  namespace example\Model;

  class example{

  protected $name = "sth";

  public function show_name(){
      echo $this-> name;
  }

  }
```

I instantiated it like below, in the Module.php file:

```
public function getServiceConfig()
{
    return array(
      'factories' => array(
        // 'example\Model\example' => function($sm){
           'example' => function($sm){
           //  $example_ = new example();
            $example_ = new example\Model\example();
             return $example_;
         },
      ),
    );
 }
```

I wrote a controller like below:

```
    namespace example\Controller;

    use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
    use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

    class IndexController extends AbstractActionController
    {

    protected $show_example_;

    public function indexAction()
    {

    return new ViewModel(array('example' => $this->show_example()));

    //  return array();
    }

    public function show_example()
    {
    if(!$this->show_example_){
     $this->show_example_ = $sm->get('example\Model\exmaple');
    }
    return $this->show_example_;
    }
```

I also wrote an index.phtml:

```
<?php

  echo $example;

 ?>
```

Could I please ask you to help me with this?

Comment: Like @Jonathan stated below, in your `index.phtml`, `$example` is an instance of your class, you need to call the `show_name` method instead of trying to echo the object itself.

Answer (score 1):

Your class should not echo the name it should just return it:

```
<?php
  namespace example\Model;

  class example{

      protected $name = "sth";

      public function show_name(){
          return $this->name;
      }    

  }
```

then in your view you would do:

```
<?php

  echo $example->show_name(); // outputs sth

 ?>
```

since `$example` is an instance of your class "example" which contains the method `show_name` which in turn returns the value "sth" which will be echoed by your view file

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in your Controller:
You have

```
public function show_example()
{
if(!$this->show_example_){
 $this->show_example_ = $sm->get('example\Model\exmaple');
}
return $this->show_example_;
}
```

And it should be:

```
public function show_example()
{
if(!$this->show_example_){
 $this->show_example_ = $sm->get('example\Model\example');
}
return $this->show_example_;
}
```

By the way what is the error message?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer but the controller that you suggested me to replace my controller with is such a same as I wrote. Could I ask you to have a look at it once again?

In the error.log there is the information that:

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: example_ in /var/www/html/zf2-tutorial/module/example/view/example/index/index.phtml on line 3, referer: http://localhost/zf2-tutorial/module/example/view/example/index/
```

and

```
     PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function show_name() on a non-object in /var/www/html/zf2-tutorial/module/example/view/example/index/index.phtml on line 3, referer: http://localhost/zf2-tutorial/module/example/view/example/index/
```